# Android populating contacts on listview only working on phones above gingerbread

Tags: android, android-contacts

ndroid populating contacts on listview only working on phones above gingerbread
The following code what i used to load contacts in a list view

```
dialog = new Dialog( AddNewFriend.this);
         dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
         dialog.setContentView(R.layout.contact_view);
         dialog.show();
        final ListView lv=(ListView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.lv_contacts);
        final EditText et_search=(EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.et_search);
         String  contact="";
            int i;

            ContentResolver cr= getContentResolver();
            Cursor c1=cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,null, null, null, ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME);
          //  Toast.makeText(c, c1.getCount()+"", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            if(c1.getCount()>0)
            {
                displ=new String[c1.getCount()];
                displ2=new String[c1.getCount()];
                c_name=new String[c1.getCount()];
                c_no=new String[c1.getCount()];
                 i=0;

            while(c1.moveToNext())
            {
                String id=c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                c_name[i]=c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                if(Integer.parseInt(c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER)))>0)
                {
                    Cursor c2=cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + "=?",new String[] {id}, null);
                    c2.moveToFirst();
                    c_no[i]=c2.getString(c2.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

                }
                    if(c_no[i]==null)
                    contact=String.format(c_name[i]+"\n");
                    if(c_name[i]==null)
                        contact=String.format(" \n"+c_no[i]);
                    else
                    contact=String.format(c_name[i]+"\n"+c_no[i]);
                    displ[i]=contact;
                    i++;
            }

          //  displ2=displ;
            for(int k=0;k<displ.length;k++)
            {
                displ2[k]=displ[k]; 
            }
            adpt=new ArrayAdapter<String>( AddNewFriend.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,displ2);
            lv.setAdapter(adpt); 
            }
```

work fine in phones with os versions above android 2.3, can anybody help?
It throws a nullPointer exception on log cat

Comment: Do you have any crash on version < 2.3? If so, please add logcut here.

Comment: crashed on every versions i tried which is < 2.3 .It throws a nullPointer exception on log cat

Comment: It's a problem with Cursor returned from Query. In every android platform Contacts has different structure of Tables. So you need to know structure of all tables and handle it in code. Did different queries for different platforms.

Comment: can you please upload a sample code for the query.it would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Add supported libraries and use managed query for more listing your contacts.
This cursor will be managed by Android so you do not need to close it.